Fixed element in Material UI SwipeableDrawer shifts position on mobile when scrolling
I'm using Material UI's SwipeableDrawer component to create a bottom drawer with a fixed action button container. The container is positioned with position: fixed; bottom: 0;. This works well on desktop browsers, but I'm encountering an issue on mobile devices.
When the content inside the SwipeableDrawer is long enough to scroll, and I scroll to the bottom and then try to scroll further, the fixed element (the action button container) shifts position and is no longer aligned to the bottom.
<SwipeableDrawer
anchor={anchor}
open={state[anchor]}
onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
>
  {/* long content */}
  <Box
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      position: "fixed",
      bottom: "0",
      left: "0",
      display: "flex",
      width: "100%",
      "> *": {
        flex: "1",
      },
    }}
  >
    <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>Cancel</Button>
    <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>Submit</Button>
  </Box>
</SwipeableDrawer>

Here is example code
and demo video
I've tried using position: sticky, but this does not meet my other requirements, so I'm not considering using sticky.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since the drawer element is already fixed positioned, putting another fixed positioned element inside it causes the problem. You should move your button container outside of the drawer, set its z-index value higher than 1200 (default z-index of drawer) and then hide it if the drawer is not open like this:
<div>
  {(['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'] as const).map((anchor) => (
    <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
      <SwipeableDrawer
        anchor={anchor}
        open={state[anchor]}
        onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
      >
        {list(anchor)}
      </SwipeableDrawer>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          position: 'fixed',
          bottom: '0',
          left: '0',
          display: state[anchor] ? 'flex' : 'none',
          width: '100%',
          zIndex: 1201,
          '> *': {
            flex: '1',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>Submit</Button>
      </Box>
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</div>

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example of the updated version your sample code.
